# Can you have pets on the Sims 3, without having the Sims 3 pet disc?

Tags: the-sims-3

Can you have pets on the Sims 3, without having the Sims 3 pet disc?
I have not thought of anything to try. I have thought until I could not think any more.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It depends on what you mean by *pets* of course, but assuming you're talking about cats, dogs and horses then no. You cannot have them without the expansion, even if you download them from the store.

> I have thought until I could not think any more.

Granted that the game is 6 years old, if you keep your eyes peeled you will likely be able to pick it up cheap.